# Geometry problem with a rectangular

Tags: geometry

Given a rectangular ABCD. Suppose that AE=EB and CE perpendicular to BD, prove that AF=AD.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: you see now. Use the property of right triangle
[image]

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you!